# Fix Warnings For COM Components Active DS

Tags: c#

I am getting alot of warnings from some very simple code that runs fine.

```
  internal void  GetActiveDirectoryDetails()
        {
            adDetails = new ActiveDirectoryDetails();
            ADSystemInfo ds = new ADSystemInfo();
            adDetails.SiteName = ds.SiteName;
            adDetails.UserName = ds.UserName;
            adDetails.DomainDNSName = ds.DomainDNSName;
            adDetails.ComputerName = ds.ComputerName;
            adDetails.ForestDNSName = ds.ForestDNSName;
            adDetails.PDCRoleOwner = ds.PDCRoleOwner;
            adDetails.SchemaRoleOwner = ds.SchemaRoleOwner;
            adDetails.SiteName = ds.SiteName;
            adDetails.UserName = ds.UserName;
        }
```

There are several warnings of the following flavor...

```
warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "ActiveDs" from path "C:\Windows\system32\activeds.tlb". The type library importer could not convert the signature for the member '_ads_attr_info.pADsValues'.

warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "ActiveDs" from path "C:\Windows\system32\activeds.tlb". At least one of the arguments for 'ITypeInfo.RemoteGetTypeAttr' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.
```

All seem to have something to do with the .tlb file how do I fix this?

Comment: That happens, not every type library feature can be properly handled by managed code.  It is almost always benign.  You can run tlbimp.exe from the Developer Command Prompt to make the conversion just once.  That produces activeds.dll.  Add a reference to it and check it into source control.  Do consider using the System.DirectoryServices namespace to leverage the built-in support for DS.

Comment: @Hans Passant Can you share an DirectoryServices code snippet that is the same as the code above?